# How to stably sort an array of objects by a series of keys such that ordering of each preceding key is preserved

Tags: typescript

I would like to build a general purpose function that can sort an array of objects using a list of keys such that the ordering of the previous key is preserved. Here is an example:

```
const input = [
  { a: 'aardvark', b: 'bear', c: 'camel', d: 1 },
  { a: 'anemone', b: 'bat', c: 'cobra', d: 6 },
  { a: 'aardvark', b: 'badger', c: 'camel', d: 2 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'bat', c: 'chicken', d: 2 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'beetle', c: 'cow', d: 1 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'bat', c: 'crab', d: 3 },
]

sortFunction(['a', 'b', 'd'], input)

// output
[
  { a: 'aardvark', b: 'badger', c: 'camel', d: 2 },
  { a: 'aardvark', b: 'bear', c: 'camel', d: 1 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'bat', c: 'chicken', d: 2 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'bat', c: 'crab', d: 3 },
  { a: 'alligator', b: 'beetle', c: 'cow', d: 1 },
  { a: 'anemone', b: 'bat', c: 'cobra', d: 6 },
]
```

The first key to sort on is, `a`, so the output first correctly sorts the data by `a` in descending order. The next key in the list is `b`, so for any item where the value of `a` is the same, the `b` keys are used to reorder only the items where `a` is the same. Finally, `d` is used to reorder only items where the value of `a` and `b` are the same. In this particular example, there are 2 items with the values of `a: alligator` and `b: bat`, so the item containing `d: 2` is placed before the item containing `d: 3`.

The issue I'm struggling with is how to make this into a generic function that can accept any array of objects and sort them by a list of keys where the value of the keys are either string on numbers as I've show in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to call [the `sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on your input with a comparator callback that compares by each key in order until it finds one that determines the sort order:

```
function sortFunction<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, string | number>>(
  keys: K[], objs: T[]
) {
  objs.sort((a, b) => {
    for (const k of keys) {
      if (a[k] < b[k]) return -1;
      if (a[k] > b[k]) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })
}
```

It's a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that constrains the `objs` input so that the array of objects is known to have `string` or `number` values at the keys in the `keys` array.

You can verify that this works as desired on your example input:

```
sortFunction(['a', 'b', 'd'], input);

console.log(input.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)).join("\n"));    
/*
"{"a":"aardvark","b":"badger","c":"camel","d":2}
{"a":"aardvark","b":"bear","c":"camel","d":1}
{"a":"alligator","b":"bat","c":"chicken","d":2}
{"a":"alligator","b":"bat","c":"crab","d":3}
{"a":"alligator","b":"beetle","c":"cow","d":1}
{"a":"anemone","b":"bat","c":"cobra","d":6}" ]
*/
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgV1gXhgbQFAxgbxgEMAuGAciKICcATANxoGtyAaGAIzPI4FMa2MYN2BEAtrwA2g2mQCMMAL6tcBYtyJheY8L0FcKHIlEHCKoDtSIyyANiUq8hUhSp1G1FuwM8itAOa81KYi4lI2MABMDqrOGpKScP7GIMHe3EYm7GbkwAAWcMBMvGAR0cqx6q4JSSlpnBm8vFCSetkiIADuEQoVTlWUNclQqfoZxiHmVhwRAMwxALrY2ABmyGDAUHDgMBCpUABi65vbYAA8ANIwvAAeUCW0EDAACtQgiEFQAJ4XvF-sABVrncHk8AEq8UB0S7saDUBD+GAAHxgYGQYj41AAfFiABSqYpfCBkC6YBbsEAcABWxJgALJ2AAlARVJSaQA6PbUKC43FEbzMtBYll4PArVIwXGgSCwJgwEArGCEiDM-CqUXwRV8zBMBYwM6cHULZnUZrIahgGAAWjkAG51aK4FqiEaYMKOEaTWaLTA7Q7FA7TVBzZaAAz2vCKRnYAPYLmHY5bcC4zCUQQ8dO0cjk+BIVDR7DSvatdmSED+XEIFBQdliIiIXH0GBCmAAKQAygB5ABynKg8LA-idX0bjMZ7KpIAQuIARAAdMAzsf27AAegAVGvV-LUNXsDgZ-gZ0QZyRjzQGMwZ6wZxxT7e-IFqNeZ8B76IJJIX7RT5EA0eTzPNxL08F87zPPgaBfN8zw-KRv1POR-2Pe8iCGOowPvTJoPfAoihKBCSD-bAANQ9CRmfG9wIfKAcNg6ZCNmZDAOPcjUkwiCmhaXg6NfLpCKQkiUKArQdC0DiaN4iwrEI2xFBnGAlnXVdsCAA)